# MDX - Is it possible to have two unrelated dimension members in one row?

Tags: mdx

I need to create the table of the following structure in MDX (to be used in SSRS report):

[image]

For that I have 2 dimensions and one measure:

1. Option dimension, with option type and option value attributes
2. Standard dimension, with IsStandard flag
3. Price measure

In first column I need to show all option type attributes,

in second all value attributes where IsStandard flag is set to [Y],

in third values chosen by user in parameters and

in fourth prices for components selected by user.

Is it possible to do the above in single MDX? Or will I be better off creating 2 distinct queries and creating 2 tables for them?

EDIT: Since my updates won't fit into the comment, I will add some thoughts here.
EXISTS function from answer below does not filter the result set, I don't get standard values but all possible values concatenated. When I issue the following code:

```
SELECT 
[Measures].[Price] ON 0,
NON EMPTY [Option].[Option Type].children
*
[Option].[Option Value].children ON 1
FROM [Cube]
WHERE
(
[Standard].[IsStandard].&[Y],
[Configurations].[Configuration].&[conf1]
)
```

It returns the default values correctly, but if I use

```
SELECT 
[Measures].[Price] ON 0,
[Option].[Option Type].children
*
EXISTS(
[Option].[Option Value].[Option Value].members
,([Standard].[IsStandard].&[Y],[Configurations].[Configuration].&[conf1])
) ON 1
FROM [Cube]
```

It does not filter the results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can accept a slightly different order of columns, then this can be done in MDX, using a calculated measure which is actually a string (as you want to see a list of attributes values in column). This avoids having the same attribute twice in the rows:

```
WITH Member Measures.[Standard Value] AS
     Generate(NonEmpty([Option].[Option Type].[Option Type].Members,
                       {([Standard].[IsStandard].&[Y],
                         Measure‌​s.[Price]
                       )}
                      ),
              [Option].[Option value].CurrentMember.Name,
              ", "
             )
SELECT {  Measures.[Standard Value], Measures.[Price] }
       ON COLUMNS,

       NON EMPTY
       [Option].[Option Type].[Option Type].Members
       *
       { @chosenValues } // the parameters value should be a comma separated list like "[Option].[Option value].[AMD], [Option].[Option value].[INTEL]"
       ON ROWS
  FROM [Your Cube]
 WHERE [Configurations].[Configuration].&[conf1]
```

You can adapt the list separator (the last argument of the `Generate` function) to anything you like.

And in case there is more than one measure group that is related to the dimensions `[Option]`, `[Standard]`, and `[Configurations]`, you should add the name of the measure group to use for determining the relationship as additional last parameter to the `Exists`, so that you and not the engine determines that. Just use the name of the measure group in either single or double quotes.

Comment: EXISTS function does not filter the set - I get all values concatenated instead of only the standard ones. I also tried FILTER and NONEMPTY, same result.

Comment: But I understood correctly that for the option values which are not standard, there does not exist any fact table entry referencing these option values and a record from the IsStandard dimension containing 'Y'?

Comment: Partially - there is also another dimension "Configurations" storing certain configurations and some configurations may have components which are standard there but not here, so I filter on ([Standard].[IsStandard].&[Y], [Configuration].&[SelectedConfiguration]) - still no filtering

Comment: @kyooryu Where does the selected configuration come into play in your query? In WHERE? In A subselect? In the rows?

Comment: It can be in either subselect or where, it doesn`t change the outcome of the rest of the query - now I used it in subselect.

Comment: @kyooryu I edited my answer, adding a WHERE clause and changing the second argument to `Exists`. WHERE is easier to handle in this case, as it sets the `CurrentMember`, while selections in a subselect are more difficult to use.

Comment: Still no filtering whatsoever. Interestingly, it doesn`t work when I want to select only [Option] cube dimension attributes either, only NON EMPTY clause works.

Comment: @kyooryu This is really difficult to "debug via discussion" without knowing the exact cube details and the requirements on the query. Maybe you can describe your cube in more detail, and write a query as you use it for testing in your question.

Comment: @kyooryu Two questions: Did you try using the name of the measure group as third parameter of `Exists`? And does this measure group/its fact table contain records relating `([Standard].[IsStandard].&[Y], Configurations].[Configuration].&[conf1])` to option values that have a measure value of `null` for Price?

Comment: Yes to both. Actually, when using third parameter I get "Measure group not found" error in the standard value column.

Comment: @kyooryu If you get get "Measure group not found", then it seems you mis-spelled the name of the measure group. But if your fact table more or less is a cross product of the dimensions, which is unusual, we have to sort out how to get the desired option values first, before applying the `Generate`. Does `NonEmpty([Option].[Option Type].[Option Type].Members, {([Standard].[IsStandard].&[Y],[Configurations].[Configuration].&[conf1],Measures.[Price])})` on the rows deliver the correct restricted option value list?

Comment: It is hard to misspell when you drag measure from cube overview window :) As for the query you posted, it returns proper values.

Comment: @kyooryu Please note that I said **Measure Group**, not **Measure**! The UI does not allow you to drag and drop measure group names. Anyway, this was nor working due to your cube structure. I edited my answer to use `NonEmpty` and the price measure instead of `Exists`, assuming the non empty price measure is the correct condition in your cube.

Comment: Okay, the current solution still did not work (now there are empty fields when there is more than one option to choose), I will merge standards with chosen directly in SSRS - anyway, I`ll give +100 for this answer for the sheer amount of effort you took to help and for clarifying a few things for me.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is, dimension will just be ignored. This is assuming you've all in the same schema / cube.

Note, depending on the OLAP Server you're using it's possible you've to change a flag that sends an error if you're using a dimensions that is not defined at Measure Group level.